# JDBC connection failed "Could not initialize class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection"

Tags: hive

My WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH:

```
${MW_HOME}/oracle_common/common/bin/CommExtEnv.sh  
WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH="${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${PROFILE_CLASSPATH}
${CLASSPATHSEP}${ANT_CONTRIB}/ant-contrib1.0b3.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${CAM_NODEMANAGER_JAR_PATH}${CLASSPATHSEP}/scratch/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}/scratch/hive-jdbc-1.2.0-standalone.jar"
```

**Stacktrace:**

> Could not establish a connection because of
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection0(DataSourceUtil.java:423)
> weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.access$000(DataSourceUtil.java:24)
> weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil$1.run(DataSourceUtil.java:285)
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)
> weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:282)
> com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:937)
> com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:524)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
> org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
> org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
> org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
> org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
> org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
> org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
> org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
> org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
> ...

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by using the latest drivers at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0

and updated by WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH with below jars

WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH=${WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH}${CLASSPATHSEP}/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}/hive-jdbc-2.0.0.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}/hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar"

I am able to create JDBC connection successfully after bouncing the Weblogic.